# mouse event using id in kineticjs

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, kineticjs

I want to add dragmove event to a particular image using id of image.It's not woring.

```
        $("#image1").on('dragmove', function(evt) {
            var shape = evt.targetNode;
            alert('you clicked on \"' + shape.getPosition().x + '\"');
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find(id)` or `findOne(id)` to get image instance on stage.

```
stage.findOne('#image1').on('dragmove', function() {
    // here this refers to image instance
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing jQuery and KineticJS. jQuery has no idea about the shapes in the stage, those are managed by KineticJS.

Try something like this:

```
var image = stage.get('#image1')[0];

image.on('dragstart', function() {
        alert('you clicked on \"' + image.position().x + '\"');
});
```

Comment: It's not working.if the image1 is dropped as a first element.var image = stage.get('#image1')  works.if image1 is dropped, after some other elements dropped var image =stage.get('#image1') is not working. @Yousif Al-Y

Comment: @BirunthaGnaneswaran I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Did you include the '[0]' at the end? Sharing some of your code can make it easier for me to help you.